# analytic multivariate Lorenz surfaces

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, economics, marginal-distribution

> I am given the projections of a multivariate probability distribution and asked to recover the multivariate distribution.

> How do I derive the copula?

> How do I use the copula to define the joint distribution function?

For continuous random variables $X,Y$ with probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, the marginal probability distribution function of $X$ is defined as:
$$ f_{X}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy$$
and similarly for $f_Y(y)$.

Here is a simple example diagram of what's going on. The black distribution is a projection and the red distribution is another projection of the multivariate distribution (in center):
[image]

In my case the probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ lives in $(0,1)^3$ and has six projections onto each face of the boundary cube $[0,1]^2.$

$$ f_{X}(x)=\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)~dy=K(s)\exp{\bigg(\frac{s}{\log(x)}\bigg)} $$

$$f_{Y}(y)=\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)~dx=K(s)\exp{\bigg(\frac{s}{\log(y)}\bigg)}$$

The other four projections can be deduced based on symmetry, $s$ is the real parameter $s \in (0,\infty)$ and $K(s)$ normalizes (Modified Bessel function of the second kind).

Now this is all related to a distribution known as a Lorenz distribution. Clearly the marginals I just defined are univariate Lorenz distrubitions (real analytic ones). Based on Taguchi's proposed multivariate extension of the Lorenz curve I can "smell" the general shape of the distribution.

Here is Taguchi's proposed multivariate Lorenz distribution and what I need my distribution to "generally look like":

[image]

Although in my case the multivariate surface is smooth and maybe real analytic.

[multivariate majorization and multivariate Lorenz ordering](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-93773-1_7)

[analytic expressions for Multivariate Lorenz surfaces](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13171-018-00158-9)

Comment: Notice that the marginals don't determine a unique joint distribution.  An example with the Gaussian distribution: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d

Comment: @PeterO. thanks Peter

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  However, my previous comment was meant to note that a set of marginals may correspond to more than one copula (and in general, they correspond to infinitely many copulas).  However, the simplest one is the product copula, which happens when the marginal random variables are independent.